# SQL Server + hibernate composite key fails on IN predicate

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, composite-key

I'm migrating some project on Hibernate (I'm not sure about version it is embedded to JBoss5.1.0GA looks like 3.x) from Oracle to SQL Server.

One of the queries on HQL looks like:

```
...
FROM k join k.defs kd
  ...
WHERE ...
   kd not in ( SELECT d.defs FROM d ...)
```

On MSSQL this query executed (and failed) as:

```
....
WHERE 
   ( 
   (kd.ITEM_ID, kd.DEF_ID) not in  (
       SELECT
          defs.ITEM_ID, defs.DEF_ID
```

My `kd` entity has compound key of 2 fields ITEM_ID and DEF_ID. SQL Server fails because in comparison with Oracle doesn't supports compound `IN` predicate.

Obviously that is a bug in mapping produced by Hibernate. My question is: How to configure/patch Hibernate to provide field-by-field comparison of enlisted sample?

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish the same thing. Left outer join includes all the rows in k and rows from d where the on matches. d is null where it doesn't match. My syntax might be off a little- I'm not where I can test it but I hope this gets you started.

```
FROM k join k.defs kd
left outer join d.defs kd
  ...
WHERE ...
    d is null
```

Comment: thank you for attention to my question. `NOT EXISTS` is more elegant way to substitute `NOT IN` predicate. But I'm going to leave it as last possible solution - because code is legacy and changes can cause side effects. So question in manipulation with hibernate - to patch (may be to some higher versions or change particular class).